# Opacity depending on the layer

Tags: after-effects

Is there any shortcut where I can apply a 0% opacity at the beginning of the layer and 100% opacity after 10 frames after the beginning of the layer and can do the reverse as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an expression on the Opacity property:

```
fade = framesToTime(10);
fadeIn = (time - inPoint) / fade;
fadeOut = (outPoint - time) / fade;
if (time < inPoint + fade) { ease(fadeIn, 0, 1) * value }
else if (time > outPoint - fade) { ease(fadeOut, 0, 1) * value }
else { value }
```

This expression will fade the layer from 0% to 100% Opacity across the first 10 frames, then fade from 100% to 0% on the last 10 frames of the layer. This is based on the layer's in and out points on the timeline.

Full tutorial (starts at 3:08):

Hope this helps!

Comment: objective and effective response